# Tello EDU Drone AI with Python

Tags: python, dji-sdk, tello-drone

I am currently working on my Bachelor's thesis, which involves AI-controlled drones utilizing image recognition to navigate through a designated course. However, I am a beginner with programming in Python. As part of my project, I am aiming to implement 8D flips into the flight sequence, but I have encountered a challenge during the process. The drone is not executing the forward flip command.

```
elif 'flip' in detectedTrafficSign:     # flip
    sendCommand2All('left 30', 4000)
    sendCommand2All('flip f' , 5000)
    flyforward = 0.5
    print ('MODE: Maneuver flip')                          
    mode_status = MODE_FLIGHT_MANEUVER
    drone_complete_action = 0
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/CrusieCrews/Tello_EDU_AI.git) code that I got from my university lecturer and modified to include additional commands for turning and flipping.

After some research, I couldn't find another command for performing a forward flip within the SDK commands. So, I reached out to ChatGPT for assistance. It provided me with a command that is supposed to change the flight mode of the drone to expert mode, and I should use it before executing the flip command. It seems to work to some extent, but in the list of SDK commands, there are only commands for 'mdirection 0/1/2.' I don't fully understand the implications of this new command, and ChatGPT couldn't provide a source for it. If anyone has insights into what this command does or has an alternative solution to fix the problem, I would greatly appreciate the help.

```
elif 'flip' in detectedTrafficSign:     # flip
    sendCommand2All('left 30', 4000)
    sendCommand2All('ap mdirection 8' , 500)
    sendCommand2All('flip f' , 5000)
    flyforward = 0.5
    print ('MODE: Maneuver flip')                          
    mode_status = MODE_FLIGHT_MANEUVER
    drone_complete_action = 0
```

Comment: What does the SDK say about what the command does? Do you mean that you want to know why ChatGPT suggested "8" when only "0/1/2" are documented?

Comment: In the [SDK User Guide](https://dl-cdn.ryzerobotics.com/downloads/Tello/Tello%20SDK%202.0%20User%20Guide.pdf), "0/1/2" stands for 0 = Enable downward detection only, 1 = Enable forward detection only, and 2 = Enable both forward and downward detection. I want to understand why ChatGPT suggested using "8" and what changes it brings. ChatGPT mentioned that it changes the flight mode to expert mode, but what does that mean exactly? Does it enable additional maneuvers or allow simultaneous flight in the x and y axes, or is it something else entirely? @mkrieger1

Comment: Possibly ChatGPT has lied.

Comment: sendCommand2All('ap mdirection 8' , 500) ??? access point  mdirection 8? it is wrong    ap command is needed to bind uav to an wifi router so that swarm can be implemented.  invalid syntax